# How to set Stage width and Height in pure AS3 project

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I was wondering if there are ways to set the width and height in a pure AS3 project...I appreciate any help....Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
[SWF(backgroundColor="0xec9900" , width="950" , height="480")]
public class Main extends Sprite
{}
```

or

```
[SWF(backgroundColor="0xec9900" , widthPercent="100" , heightPercent="100")]
public class Main extends Sprite
{}
```